# Is "At which he was really shocked" grammatical?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, idioms, prepositions

> Last month Qziz was told that he had been laid off. At which he was really shocked

Is the second sentence grammatical? Is the preposition *at* used appropriately here, or should I use a different one? Google Books showed 552,000 results for [“at which he was”](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22at%20which%20he%20was%22&oq=%22at%20which%20he%20was%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.10388j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22at%20which%20he%20was%22&tbm=bks)

Comment: I think it is unusual to start a sentence with "at which". Moreover, it is unclear what "at which" here refers to. I would prefer "He was shocked by this". I am not sure if your sentence is grammatical, or not.

Comment: Is it an interrogative sentence? Or you didn't put another independent clause before "at which". Please dit your question. Otherwise your question might be closed as "off-topic". Thanks.

Comment: Relative clauses don't have to be in the same printed sentence as their antecedents. Variations in punctuation are normal for colloquial speech; after all, there is no punctuation in speech.